# Why is the output showing d=4 instead of d=8

Tags: c

Why is the output showing d=4 instead of d=8 in the first printf statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 4, c = 3, d = 4;
    int y = (c = 5) || (d = 8);

    printf("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d, d=%d\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`||` short circuits, so in:

```
y = (c = 5) || (d = 8);
```

The `d = 8` is never evaluated.

That is, since `(c = 5)` evaluates as true, there is no reason to evaluate the `(d = 8)` to determine the truthiness of the expression; so it is not evaluated.